# PHP Web Crawler shows an Parse error of unexpected colan (:)

Tags: php

I tried to execute this basic webcrawler php code in my xampp while it shows a error like `unexpected (:) in target line`

My code as follows::

```
<?php
include_once('simple_html_dom.php');
$target_url = “http://www.websitename.com/”;
$html = new simple_html_dom();
$html->load_file($target_url);
foreach($html->find(‘a’) as $link){
echo $link->href.”<br />”;
}
?>
```

the error points at `$target_url = "http://www.websitename.com/";`

Any Suggestions are helpful.

Comment: will you tell on which line number error is coming

Comment: its on the target_url line

Comment: for a testing just put  include_once('simple_html_dom.php'); below the $target_url
and then tell me what's the output

Comment: still the same error

Comment: try error_reporting(0) once sometimes it is due to wrong block in html code e.g a div is opened but not closed.

Comment: you are using single and double quotation marks (“ ” ‘ ’)  instead of regular quotes(' ' " "). Most likely due to the editor you are using

Comment: @danig you should post this as an answer ;)

Answer (score 1):

you are using single and double quotation marks (“ ” ‘ ’) instead of regular quotes(' ' " "). Most likely due to the editor you are using

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php
include_once('simple_html_dom.php');
$url = "http://www.freelancer.com";
$html = new simple_html_dom();
$html->load_file($url);
foreach($html->find("a") as $link){
echo $url.$link->href."<br/>";
}
?>
```